# Wrapping J's Adverse primitive (::)

Tags: j

Usually, I will use the `::` primitive thus:

```
SomeVariable"_ :: ] DefaultValue
```

I'm looking for a way to wrap that ugly SOB. I'm trying to reason it. Normally, it would be with a tacit definition. This, for example:

```
default =: 13 : 'x"_ :: ] y'
```

fails miserably. Because, of course, in this context:

```
SomeVariable default DefaultValue
```

if SomeVariable doesn't exist, J will throw a valence error.

So, how can you wrap `::`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed wrap :: but if you want to give it a verb argument, you need to deal with the syntactic issues.

For example, you can use an adverb:

```
fault=:1 :0
  u"_ :: ]
)
```

Or you could convert the verb you are manipulating into a gerund and pass that in (but that would be ugly, so I do not think you want that).

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know that! That is totally what I want, not for verbs, but really just for nouns. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use,

```
ORdef_z_ =: ".@[^:(_1< 4!:0@<@[)

 'asd' ORdef 3  NB. asd not assigned, returns right.
3
 asd =. 'asd' ORdef 3
asd=.'asd' ORdef 22  NB. will return 3 due to previous assignment
asd
```

3